# Composite variation or standard deviation without common means for more than 2 samples

Tags: statistics, standard-deviation

I know the formula for pooled variance is [image] if the mean for all samples are equivalent and I know that if I want to combine the sigma of two samples with different mu, then the formula is [image], but what would I do if I wanted something like the second formula with more samples? I'm working with 51 samples. I suppose I could use the second formula to combine 2 samples at a time until I got all 51, so I'd do the same thing 50 times, but that sounds terribly cumbersome and while that's work I'd be willing to do, I would strongly rather not if there happens to be an easier way to do this.

I also have access to LibreOffice Calc, which should relieve me of some of the workload.

To summarize, I have the mus and sigmas of 51 different samples and need to find the sigmas of all of the samples combined in the most efficient manner possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, Charles Zaiontz answered my question! ^_^

http://www.real-statistics.com/descriptive-statistics/measures-variability/measures-variability-detailed/#comment-848425